# Debian OpenSSL zscaler issue php

Tags: php, openssl, debian, zscaler

I'm stuck at my Debian configuration. The problem is as follow:

The internet connection is handled by a zScaler proxy server, performing TLS/SSL inspection.
However, this causes applications to break.

I believed I narrowed it down to a SSL issue, because from command-line testing (e.g. curl, wget or openssl itself, I receive:

```
Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

Now, when I test with e.g. openssl and use the -CAfile parameter, it works:

```
sudo openssl s_client -CAfile /etc/ssl/certs/zScalerRootCA.crt -connect kimai.org:443 -proxy zscalerIP:port
```

the outcome is:

```
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

Meaning that when I point it directly to the certificate it works. However, the application I use (symfony php), is using the get_file_contents() function. This however times out. And I'm pretty sure it has to do with the same issue.

I've tried 100 things and I'm lost now. I just can't get it to work.

- Why do I have to tell openssl from command line to use that certificate (while it's in the certificate store)?
- How do I get e.g. get_file_contents() to work? (I want it to use the system environment and not hardcode it into the application)

I'm happy to share any config, no problem!

Comment: Just because it is in your certificate store, doesn't necessarily mean cURL automatically "knows" that it needs to use it, in this situation. You made a request to `kimai.org`, and your system likely has no reason whatsoever, to associate your proxy server's CA file with that.

Comment: As for `file_get_contents`, which I assume you meant here - you would have to pass in an SSL context, that you have configured to use those CA files ... https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php

Comment: Thank CBroe, for taking the time. For the 'file_get_contents', means there is no way to get it from system settings? I was afraid of this already, but maybe someone knows a different way....

Comment: I don't know of any other way, than passing in a context explicitly. There are no config options to specify any "defaults" to be used in this situation, as far as I know.

Comment: At least I could not find it either. So now I have to nice task to find the class in the source code where the httpClient is set/ used and then alter is with the SSL context....:-(